# Can't see rotated picture after reloading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, image-rotation

I've made a rotate action for uploaded pictures using carrierwave. Pictures are rotated and saved correctly, BUT after they're saved, page is reloaded and I can't see rotated pictures. (in development this works, but not in production - Heroku) From S3 bucket I can see pictues are rotated correctly instantly. Only after I do in browser:

```
Open image in new tab > manually reload page > then I see correctly rotated picture.
```

How can I solve this? Thanks.

class Ad:

```
attr_accessor :rotate_picture_side
attr_accessor :picture_index

after_save {rotate_selected_picture if should_rotate_picture?}

private
def rotate_selected_picture
  self.pictures[picture_index].recreate_versions!
end

def should_rotate_picture?
  self.rotate_picture_side.present? && self.picture_index.present?
end
```

class PicturesController:

```
  def update
    @ad.rotate_picture_side = params[:rotate_picture_side]
    @ad.picture_index = params[:id].to_i
    @ad.save
    redirect_to edit_ad_path(@ad, anchor: "rotate-picture #
     {@ad.picture_index}")
  end
```

class PicturesUploader:

```
   def rotate_picture
     manipulate! do |pic|
       if model.rotate_picture_side == "right"
         pic.rotate "90"
       elsif model.rotate_picture_side == "left"
        pic.rotate "270"
       end
       pic #returns the manipulated picture
     end
   end
```

Comment: is there `RMagick` installed in your production server. And also try to install maybe `JPEG`, something like: `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev` (if it;s linux)

Comment: I use mini_magick + carrierwave and yes it's included in production. As I said in development environment it works as it's supposed to, only production is the problem.